# GitHub for Macでrevertボタンが押せない

Tags: github, macos

GitHub for Mac で`revert`できないのですが皆さんできていますか？

ついこの前までできてたと思うのですが、`History`画面の以下の設定アイコンが押せなくなってます。私だけでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: Github for Macのバージョンの教えて頂けるとわかりやすいです。

Comment: pull requestのみの対応とかいうのは関係ないでしょうか? 2014年6月からこうなったようです。 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25101983/why-cant-i-revert-commits-directly-on-github

Answer (score 1):

最新のバージョンPan Era (196)で試しに実行したところ問題なく、**History画面の設定アイコンをクリックしてrevertをする**ことが出来ました。

History部分の設定アイコンがクリックできないのは正しくSyncできていないのが原因かもしれません。再度そのレポジトリをGithub for Macに加えてみるなど行ってみるといいと思います

### 参照

- [Github for Macのバージョンについて](https://mac.github.com/release-notes.html)

Comment: 仰るとおりsync後はrevertできました。（設定アイコンを押せるようになりました。） ありがとうございます。